# Gmail contextual gadget Publish and install but not show in Gmail

Tags: gmail, google-apps-marketplace, gmail-contextual-gadgets

I'm trying to build a gmail contextual gadget. I am testes in on my domain it working fine on domain but whenever I am install from market place link it show it install but not show in inbox please any one help me [This is my gadget XML](https://googledrive.com/host/0B3dGitT-NxUMc3IwVDMycl9paDA/gadget.xml)

Comment: how do you test on your domain ? do you have a api console with appsmarket sdk enabled ? did you configure the COB extension ?

Comment: Thanks Koma for your reply. 

Actually, when I try to deploy the gadget from Google Apps console, it works perfect on my own domain.

However, when I publish now using the COB extension through Google Apps API console, following all the steps listed here: https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/preparing, it gets installed on other domains, but the gadget itself never shows up. I waited for 2 days and also used the no-cache option with no avail.

Would really appreciate your help and support.

Comment: @AnilUgale I am getting same issue with my gadget. Did your gadget show up now? I used following values to populate the COB Extention fields `Extractor Url:http://extractor_url.xml  
Gadget Url:http://gadget_url.xml  
Extractor param name: kept this empty  
Extractor param value:kept this empty  
Scopes: Selected : Mail - To Recipient Names  
 and Mail - Sender Address` Could you please let me know if I am missing anything? Thanks a lot.